# Does iOS Instruments miss thread stack deallocations, or is this leak real?

Tags: ios, multithreading, xcode-instruments

At launch our app starts a large number of threads to asynchronously load files, thus:

`if( !pthread_create( &_handle,0,run,this ) ){ pthread_detach( _handle ); }`

According to XCode, all these threads complete and disappear. However, according to the Allocations instrument, 50mb of VM:Stack remains allocated, with only a handful of the file-loader thread stacks being deallocated.

If I replace pthread_detach with pthread_join, Allocations reports the stack memory as deallocated correctly.

This behaviour manifests in XCode 11.3.1 when allocating around a hundred threads in rapid succession on a device running iOS 12.1.4 using the code above.

I need to know whether the failure is with the instrument, or in the threading itself. I suspect the former but have been unable to prove that to my own satisfaction.

Comment: You say "at launch". My experience is that Instruments is pretty much completely unreliable on what's going on during launch. Just to give an example, if I deliberately create a leak in `viewDidLoad`, it doesn't show, but if I move it to two seconds later, it does. So I would try artificially moving all this activity to later in the lifetime of the app just to see what the Instruments readings are then.

Comment: Thanks :) Moving things around to check would be more effort than it's worth - it's just good to know there are things the instruments can miss.